# whats the most simple and fast string-matching algo in case of a small number of patterns in dictionary , to find in a smal string

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a large number of text files containing small conversations which themselves contain small strings (<1000 words).
I also have a list of tags and phrases I want to search in those text files.

So, I need a search algorithm which is

1. easy to understand.
2. easy to implement.
3. and give fairly good results in terms of time efficiency (for each file)

Any suggestions?

Comment: "easy" and "fairly good results" is subjective. Could you please try to rephrase your question so that it is less abstract?

Comment: For a large number of smallish text files, you might as well use a regular expression. Super easy to implement, easy to understand if you know basics of regexps, very good performance (to the point where you'll likely spend more time reading the files than searching them). You can speed them up even more by [`triegex`](https://github.com/ZhukovAlexander/triegex).

Comment: The [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) is relatively easy to understand, well-documented, easy to implement (Python implementations exist), fast, and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to lookup a word in a set of words, a data structure of choice is the trie. A trie is a tree such that every node conveys a letter and points to all the next letters in the vocabulary.

For instance if the set is `'cat'`, `'carrot'`, `'clock'`, the root of the trie will point to a node `'c'`. Then `'c'` will point to `'a'` and `'l'`, and `'a'` to `'t'` and `'r'`. The trie structure can continue to the end of the words, or you can keep the single suffixes separately.

Now if you search the word `'card'`, you will follow the nodes `'c' > 'a' > 'r'` and see that there is no `'d'` and conclude that the word is absent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

---

You can adapt the idea to your case, replacing "word" by "sentence" and "letter" by "word". As the set of words is larger than the alphabet, you will have to use hashmaps in each node, to associate the possible words to pointers to the following nodes.

To solve your initial problem, take every word in turn and compare it and match it and its successors to the trie. I guess that the total running time will be on the order of the number of words in the text times the average length of the matches, times what it takes to perform a hashmap lookup.

---

For easy development, consider first implementing a word lookup in a standard trie.

Comment: I commented on the question, but see `triegex` - creates a trie in regex, so you get best of both worlds: trie search that is in C, not in Python. Superfast.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd suggest the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), which is essentially a modified trie.